# ¿Qué está mal en esta prueba?

Tags: nodejs

Hoy hice una prueba técnica con **`Node.js`**, a la cuál considero que hice bien. No me generó error, pero el *output* no era como en la prueba se esperaba, por lo que escribo esta pregunta a razón de si alguien podría por favor indicarme en qué me equivoqué.

La prueba iba así:

> In the JavaScript file, write a program to perform a GET request on
> the route *oculto* which contains a data key and the value is a string
> which contains items in the format: key=STRING, age=INTEGER. Your goal
> is to count how many items exist that have an age equal to 32. Then
> you should create a write stream to a file called output.txt and the
> contents should be the key values (from the json) each on a separate
> line in the order they appeared in the json file (the file should end
> with a newline character on its own line). Finally, then output the
> SHA1 hash of the file.

Y mi código era así:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto')

https.get('ruta oculta', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (d) => {
        data += [d]
    })

    resp.on('end', () => {
        let parsedData = data.split(',')
        .filter(data => !data.indexOf(' age='))
        .map(data => data.replace(' age=', ''))
        .map(data => parseInt(data))
        .filter(data => {
            return (data === 32)
        }).length

        console.log('Number of items whose age is equal to 32: ' + parsedData)

        const stream = fs.createWriteStream('output.txt')

        let keys = data.split(',')
        .filter(data => !data.indexOf(' key='))
        .map(data => data.replace(' key=', ''))
        .map(data => {
            stream.write(data + '\n')
        })

        const read = fs.createReadStream('output.txt')
        const sha = crypto.createHash('sha1')

        read.addListener('data', function(data) {
            sha.update(data)
        })

        read.addListener('close', function() {
            console.log(sha.digest('hex'))
        })
    })

});
```

Un **ejemplo del input** era: `{"data":"key=IAfpK, age=32, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=40, key=9snd2, age=32"}`

El **file contents (output.txt)** debía contener:

```
IAfpK
9snd2
```

El **output esperado** era ***7caa78c7180ea52e5193d2b4c22e5e8a9e03b486***

Sinceramente, no sé qué podría estar mal. Ojalá alguien pudiera ayudarme, porque sí quedé muy perdido (ya que no hubo retroalimentación).

Comment: No lo he probado... pero así por encima, veo que el input era un JSON, lo más factible habría sido convertir eso a JSON y acceder a la propiedad `data`. Tu intentaste procesar el `string` directamente. Por esa misma razón, el `!data.indexOf(' key=')` no te funcionaba bien, porque en el caso del primer elemento no contiene un espacio antes del `key`